# SharePoint Online Development

Tags: sharepoint-addin, upgrade, update

I'm developing add-ins for Sharepoint Online and I got a question. Did Microsoft ever said that my add-in code will always be supported ?

I'm wondering because they are always pushing new features to Office 365.

Comment: Now, any server side code-based sandbox solutions/custom webparts are not supporting any more in SP Online. But in SharePoint provider hosted app you can use  code/C#.
Apart from this, You can use JSOM, REST API based solutions, SharePoint hosted apps in SharePoint online.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already knew that. What I want to know is if I can use for example a function in CSOM and be sure that it will always be supported in SharePoint Online.